# How to slide geometry past an edge?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am trying to slide a bunch of selected edges past an edge, as is done at [19:27 of the blender guru tutorial on "how to make a beer"](http://youtu.be/Xbc3KMIOuKM?t=19m7s).

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd> to select the edge loop
2. Press <kbd>G</kbd> twice
3. Move the mouse cursor up and down, while holding <kbd>Alt</kbd>

The edges only move down and also along the plane in which the circular loop resides (imagine for instance the top of the cylinder being the loop, and I'm trying to slide the edges to form a concavity in the cylinder)

I want the edges to move past the vertex loop.. Can someone help me?

[image]

Comment: as far as i can see from the image the geometry which you are trying to slide on, does not continue upwards... is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct.. if i keep moving the mouse cursor up , it slides along the top of the plane

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the vertices selected, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to ensure that you are *vertex sliding*, not *edge sliding*. Pressing <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> automatically picks between the two operators based on the selection, and you cannot edge slide geometry past adjacent edge loops (you can with *vertex* slide though).

Once you are in the vertex slide operator, press <kbd>C</kbd> to disable clamp (or hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>).

[image]

Note that disabling clamp locks the selected vertices to the edges which they are sliding on when you press <kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

---

However in this particular situation I think <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> is a faster method, as [mentioned by G.Rassovsky](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14893/599).

Comment: I never knew about G G, +1

Comment: Ah , awesome , seems to work !! :) :) Thank you !! . Can you also tell me what screen shot software you are using here.. i would like to make my questions and answers more informative as you have done so wonderfully ..

Comment: Lice is the screen capture software used by many people here. It creates .gif animations.

Comment: @SreekanthNarayanaswamy I use [LICEcap](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/7019/1279), running in wine.

Comment: Shift+V? That's a dream! I have always wondered how I could do that. Thank you Gandalf!