# Move vertex away from edge in current direction

Tags: modeling

The `Slide` tool `GG` is perfect to move vertices along an edge when modeling organic shapes. But what if I want to move a vertex (make the edge longer) in the end of an edge away, but still in the current direction as the edge? Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Like this? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14892/how-to-slide-geometry-past-an-edge/14894#14894 Or this? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2981/vertex-slide-past-edge-limit/2982#2982