# Is there a way to extrude a face while following the angles of the sides?

Tags: modeling

I tried extruding the edges along their normals but it would not follow the angle properly, so i was wondering if there was a way to extrude the face and as i pull it out, it will scale it to keep the edges co planar to their origin edges and corresponding face.

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4r6Hs.jpg

Comment: What you describe sounds like a regular extrude, unless I misunderstood. If that isn't happening then something is wrong, possibly duplicate geometry, overlapping faces, or inconsistent normals.

Comment: i believe you will find what you're looking for here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7365/extrude-faces-along-local-normals :]

Comment: I tried the suggested methods, and unless i was doing them improperly, it does not seem to be the solution. Please excuse the beveling, but i went ahead and did the procedure by hand, maybe this will give more insight into exactly what i am looking to do.
http://imgur.com/a/WnJ2x

Comment: Stumbled upon this question searching how to pull a face while confining adjacent faces to their respective planes. Discovered a method to achieve what I needed, by using Edge Slide and pressing C to release Clamp, similar to: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14892